# NestJS strategy for processing image from social signin (oauth) before saving to db?

Tags: nestjs

I wanted to request some opinions and / or approaches on how to handle the above.

I’m using passport with an oauth strategy for Google sign-in to get access to a users profile, from there I save it to my db.

I want to process the profile image and create a blurhash from it before saving this updated user object to my db.

I’ve already got it all working via a function which I inject via the constructor of my auth service and do all the processing inside of a register method within it.

The approach doesn’t seem very elegant though. I feel that there must be a tidier way via interceptors and / or pipes. But all the examples I’ve come across don’t really deal with async processes via those decorators.

Furthermore, I guess the blocking aspect of having to await those operations before saving to the db may not be the correct way of doing it?

Here is the current code:

image.service.ts

```
import * as path from 'path';

import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import axios from 'axios';
import { encode } from 'blurhash';
import * as Sharp from 'sharp';

const IMAGE_UPLOAD_PATH = 'public/img';

@Injectable()
export class ImageService {
  async saveImageFromUrl(imageUrl: string, width: number): Promise<string> {
    const filename = `${Date.now()}.webp`;
    const imageResponse = await axios({
      url: imageUrl,
      responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    });
    const buffer = Buffer.from(imageResponse.data, 'binary');
    await Sharp(buffer)
      .resize(width, width, { fit: 'cover' })
      .webp({ effort: 3 })
      .toFile(path.join(IMAGE_UPLOAD_PATH, filename));

    return filename;
  }

  async getBlurhash(filename: string): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      Sharp(`${IMAGE_UPLOAD_PATH}/${filename}`)
        .raw()
        .ensureAlpha()
        .resize(32, 32, { fit: 'inside' })
        .toBuffer((err, buffer, { width, height }) => {
          if (err) {
            reject(err);
          }
          resolve(encode(new Uint8ClampedArray(buffer), width, height, 4, 4));
        });
    });
  }
}
```

auth.service.ts

```
  async registerUser(user: OAuthUser) {
    try {
      const { imageUrl, ...rest } = user;
      const AVATAR_WIDTH = 96;
      const username = generateFromEmail(rest.email, 5);
      const imagePath = await this.imageService.saveImageFromUrl(
        imageUrl,
        AVATAR_WIDTH,
      );
      const blurHash = await this.imageService.getBlurhash(imagePath);
      const newUser = await this.usersService.createUser({
        ...rest,
        username,
        avatar: {
          create: {
            url: imagePath,
            blurHash,
            width: AVATAR_WIDTH,
            height: AVATAR_WIDTH,
          },
        },
      });
      return this.generateTokens(newUser);
    } catch (e) {
      throw new InternalServerErrorException(e);
    }
  }
```

Could anyone advise me as to the correct NestJS way of doing this please?

Thanks in advance.